# php array : in one line, how to get an unknown value from a known key?

Tags: php, optimization

I have this array - **it is a multidimensional array, and i don't know the 0 index** :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 1111
            [bar] => example
        )

)
```

And I need, in one line, with native php functions, to get the value from the key `bar`. I tried much combination with `current`, `key`, `array_keys`, and so on.
With `current($array)` I got :

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 1111
    [bar] => example
)
```

I discover `array_keys`, which allow me, with the second argument, to specify a value to find. But I didn't know the value, only the key, and `array_values` didnt propose a second argument to find (:o).

Here I am now : `current(array_keys(array_flip(current($b))), 'bar')` didn't work. But

```
$c = array_flip(current($b));
print_r(current(array_keys($c, 'bar')));
```

works - I get "example". (By the way, why these 2 lines are working and not the previous one ?).

And I know, it's ugly to use `array_flip` for this, but I don't know how to do otherwise. Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Reason you *need* it in one line?

Comment: "The" key `bar`? Your array contains an "etc" part. Who says there's no other `bar` in there? Also, if you need to do it on one line, write a function. The function call would be an one-liner.

Comment: I want to use it in one line - my business. Forget the etc. part, I ll remove it.

Comment: You are MASSSIVELY overthinking/overcomplicating things. Check out HankyPanky's answer below.

Comment: Yeah, but my curiosity is here ! I want to know if there is a way, with NATIVE php function, to get that result.

Comment: @Ash_ is it a multidimensional array ? I mean do you know the index 0 ?

Comment: Yeah it's a multi. And no, I don't know the index 0.

Comment: @Ash_: Well, PHP 5.4 allows `reset($array)['bar']`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Ash_ Check my cryptic answer :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in PHP 5.4+ :

```
<?php
$a = array(array('foo' => 1111, 'bar' => 'example'));
print_r(current($a)['bar']);
?>
```

Comment: God, you're right : http://codepad.viper-7.com/fCiVWz
Ok for PHP-5.4, that is great.

Comment: Yeah if there is no 'bar' key. But it is a notice - ok for me ! Both answer are good, so.

Answer (score 5):

What stops you from using

```
$value=$myArray[0]["bar"];
echo $value;
```

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: But that's too simple and doesn't call functions! :p

Comment: @jon: it is the answer, however. OP's obviously massively overcomplicating/overthinking things...

Comment: @Jon but isn't it what they are looking for?

Comment: I obviously don't want to use `[0]` thing. Don't ask me why !

Comment: @MarcB: How is it the answer? The OP clearly stated that they do not know the key `0`. Of course there are many ways to work around that, but this answer doesn't show them. Also, I feel the fact that this answer is grammatically a *question* should be enough to skip the discussion. If you are not sure, use a comment to ask for more information first and *then* give an answer.

Comment: You become a bid childish, imho. I specified that I didn't know the index (in my example, 0). I'm sorry to irritating you.

Comment: @jon: at the time, the OP hadn't said they didn't know the key. That was edited in later.

Comment: @Jon Please review the question edit history to be able to make an informed comment. The 0 key part was added later

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask me how LOL:

```
$a = array(array('foo' => 1111, 'bar' => 'example'));
echo array_map(function($v){if(isset($v['bar'])){return $v['bar'];}}, $a)[0];
```

**Note:**

- This works only with the latest versions of PHP **5.4+**
- This will throw an error if there isn't a "bar" key

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IHqJfq).

---

Better solution:

```
$a = array(
    array('aaa' => 2222, 'bbb' => '333'),
    array('foo' => 1111, 'bar' => 'example'),
    array('wut' => 'lol', 'zzz' => 'ggg')
);

echo array_values(array_filter(array_map(function($v){if(isset($v['bar'])){return $v['bar'];}}, $a)))[0];
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rg9fgX).

Comment: Yeah it's pretty good. But well, you us a local function ;) EDIT : Look @b4v answer : codepad.viper-7.com/fCiVWz

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this?

```
$c = $b[0]['bar'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(array('foo' => 1111, 'bar' => 'example'));
echo $a[0]['bar'];
```

example

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
echo $array[0]['bar'];
```

Or, using PHP functions:

```
echo array_pop(array_shift($array));
```

It will extract the first element of `$array`:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 1111
    [bar] => example
)
```

Then extract and display the last element of this array:

```
example
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use [0], you can use this instead:

```
$value = null;
foreach($array as $each)
{
   if(isset($each['bar']))
      $value = $each['bar'];
}
```

Comment: And I don't want a loop neither. ;)

Comment: Well, now you're just being difficult. :-P